# java unmarshalling complex types in Netbeans

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

I am trying to unMarshall XML data from a file with the following Schema file, using NetBeans 8.2, in a java Web Application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/xSchema"
            xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/xSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

        <xsd::complexType name="xItem">

                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="item1" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="item2" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="item3" type="xsd:int"/>

                    <xsd:element name="x-price">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name = "item4" type="xsd:string"/>
                                <xsd:element name = item5" type = "xsd:float"/>
                                <xsd:element name = "item6" type="xsd:string"/>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>

                </xsd:sequence>

            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:element name = "xList">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="x_details" type="tns:xItem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>


</xsd:schema>
```

I created an XML Document using NetBeans and populated that with data, matching the Schema file.
The XML schema is bound to the Java Web Application using Jaxb.  I have created the unmarshalling code using the jaxbu method, which looks like this

```
   xList currentx = new xList();

    //UnMarshal data from XML to Object
    try {
        javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbCtx = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(currentx.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbCtx.createUnmarshaller();
        currentx = (xList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(fileHandle); //NOI18N
    } catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException ex) {
        // XXXTODO Handle exception
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("global").log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex); //NOI18N
    }
```

The resulting ArrayList currentx, contains all the instances of item1, item2 and item 3.  It does not however appear to contain items 4 and 5. 'fileHandle' is a FILE object, and is obviously pointing to the correct file.
The generated files include classes for xItem and a nested static class for x-price, but whenever I try to retrieve data from the nested class, I get a null pointer exception for items4, 5 and 6, but can read items 1,2 and 3. The unmarshalling function appears to perform without any exceptions being created.
Am I using the right methods for unmarshalling all the data or am I missing something to deal with the x-price ( items 4, 5 and 6)? How is that done ?

XLM first data record and header:

```
<ns1:xList
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:ns1='http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/xSchema'
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/xSchema xSchema1.xsd'>
    <ns1:x_details>
        <ns1:item1>AA</ns1:item1>
        <ns1:item2>AA</ns1:item2>
        <ns1:aitem3>212</ns1:item4>
        <ns1:x-price>
            <ns1:item4>GBP</ns1:item4>
            <ns1:item5>75.26</ns1:item5>
            <ns1:item6>04/12/2018</ns1:item6>
        </ns1:x-price>
    </ns1:x_details>
```

Comment: I usually create sample data in c# and serialize so I can see the xml that is produced and compare against the given xml so I can see the differences.

Comment: You missing one double quotes in XML Scheme for item5  `<xsd:element name = item5" type = "xsd:float"/>` Also please use xml validator for validate you xml.

Comment: Just checked the XML schema and the original has the double quote mark. Rechecked the XML Validation and "0 error(s), 0 Warning(s)."

Answer (score 0):

In your example Schema your schema seems to be invalid:

`<xsd:element name = item5" type = "xsd:float"/>`

and should be

`<xsd:element name = "item5" type = "xsd:float"/>`

also it is hard to help if your real data is missing (your XML). Could you add a full XML example?

Comment: The original is OK, thats a typo in my asking the question.

Comment: could you please add a full XML sample of your data?